# Vent-free fireplace flame control/color doesn't seem right

Tags: fireplace, natural-gas

I have a [Superior VRL4543](http://superiorfireplaces.us.com/products/vrl4543) vent-free fireplace. For the most part it seems to be doing its job and not acting up. However, it doesn't seem to be performing as-advertised.

## From manufacturer's website

The description on the site explicitly states the following:

- Dancing yellow flames
- Six flame settings for precise heat control

This is what is pictured:

[image: Fireplace flames as pictured on website]

## As-Installed

Our flames are very very blue (slightly orange tips). Definitely not yellow or anything near the picture. Additionally, the "Six flame settings consist of an "A" and a "B" setting on the remote. "A" goes from 1-7, "B" goes from 1-3. Regardless of changes to "A" or "B" they seem to have no effect (or so little that you can't actually distinguish the difference).

The manual is little/no help and the "contact us" on the website says to get in touch with a dealer. Getting in contact with my dealer has given little/no help and when they came out to look at it basically just added the "embers" and left. This picture is about the most orange/yellow the flames have ever been.

[image: Observed flames in my home - mostly blue]

The manual also displays a danger warning about "yellow-tipping" as dangerous and giving off increased levels of CO. However, it states **`"! If you see this, turn it off and see troubleshooting on page X".`** Page X is indeed the troubleshooting section and doesn't mention a single thing about "yellow-tipping" or the color of the flames at all.

Is this right? Am I missing something here? There a setting off someplace?

Location: USA - AR.

Comment: You may want to contact the manufacturer to be sure but that flame looks good to me.  BTW, you will definitely want to install a CO detector!

Comment: Manufacturer provides regular consumers with no way to contact them. New construction so there's CO detectors all over the place.